# Is there a way to scan barcodes of a product using an IOS device and acquire an input of what the product is(eg. cocacola, bag of chip...)

Tags: ios, swift, database, camera, barcode

My team and I are developing an IOS application that records the daily carbon footprint of the user. We want to implement a barcode feature that scans the barcode of any product they buy. We expect the app to convert the barcode into a google search which should show the information about the product. Then we want to take that information into an algorithm that sends an output of how much carbon emission the product emits. Through our user interface, the app hopefully tracks and shapes the user's carbon footprint.

Comment: Maybe this can provide you with more insight :) https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-scan-a-qr-code

Comment: Scanning a barcode is easy.  Finding a database of UPC codes and what products they are is a request for an off-site resource and is unfortunately off-topic of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I would try barcode lookup API, to check if the barcode actually contained an UPC. Link: https://www.barcodelookup.com/api

Comment: Another option is to use BlinkReceipt. Instead of scanning barcodes, you can get product information by scanning retail receipts with the product names there. It might be an even simpler for the end user. https://www.blinkreceipt.com.